# Proof: For every $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha \not= 0$, there exists a unique $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha \beta = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove the following:

> For every $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha \not= 0$, there exists a unique $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha \beta = 1$.

There are two steps to this proof:

1. I first need to prove that, for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, where $\alpha \not= 0$, there does exist $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha\beta = 1$.
2. I then prove that, for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, where $\alpha \not= 0$, there exists a **unique** $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha\beta = 1$.

My proof follows.

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, where $\alpha \not= 0$, and $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$. Also, I will assume that it is valid to assume knowledge of the fact that the inverse of a complex number is also a complex number. Otherwise, I'm not sure how one would do the proof.

1. \begin{alignat}{2}
   \alpha\beta &= \alpha \alpha^{-1} & &\text{(The inverse of a complex number is also a complex number.} \\
   & & &\text{Therefore, since $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$, we can set $\beta = \alpha^{-1}.)$} \\
   &= 1 \tag*{$\blacksquare$}
   \end{alignat}
2. Here, I prove that $\beta$ is unique by assuming that there are two objects $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, and then show that they must therefore be the same object.

$$\begin{align} \alpha \beta_1 = 1, \\ \alpha \beta_2 = 1 \end{align}$$

Subtracting the two equations, we get

$$\begin{align} &\alpha \beta_1 - \alpha \beta_2 = 0 \\ &\Rightarrow \alpha(\beta_1 - \beta_2) = 0, \\ &\Rightarrow \beta_1 - \beta_2 = 0 \ \ \ \text{(Since $\alpha \not= 0$.)} \\ &\Rightarrow \beta_1 = \beta_2 \ \ \ \tag*{$\blacksquare$} \end{align}$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my proof. If there are any errors, please point out the specific error and explain the correct way.

Comment: Are you given that for every $x \in \mathbb R, \exists!y \in \mathbb R$  s.t. $xy=1$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes. For this part of the textbook, I think we can assume the properties of the real numbers. But how could such a fact be used for this proof?

Comment: Do you know how to find the inverse of $a+bi$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Do you mean in a rigorous manner? I just know that it is obviously $\dfrac{1}{a + bi}$. Or is the key to this proof to then rationalize the denominator?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think you're on the right track here, because, for every other proof of the properties of complex numbers that I have done, I used the analogous real number property. In this case, I couldn't figure out what to do, which is why I got so confused.

Comment: Make the denominator real, to show the inverse is of the form $c+di$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ahh, I see where you’re going with this. So we rationalize the denominator and then factor out the denominator, which leaves us with the denominator multiplied by a complex number?

Comment: We make the denominator a non-zero real number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As José Carlos Santos points out in his answer, the fact that every $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha \ne 0$ has an inverse is precisely what you have to prove, so you can't assume it in your proof.

J. W. Tanner's answer is technically correct, but it does rather assume that you already "magically" know what the inverse $\beta$ of $\alpha$ is.

In contrast, Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer shows how you could "discover" for yourself that the inverse $\beta$ of $\alpha$ exists, and that it has the form given in J. W. Tanner's answer.

However, I find some aspects of his answer confusing, so - with apologies - I present a slightly different version of essentially the same argument. (I hope that I haven't just introduced confusions of my own!)

First, I make some further remarks on the proof you've presented:

---

One flaw in your proof that hasn't been mentioned is that you repeat essentially the same argument in 1 and 2.

In 1, you conclude from $\alpha\beta = \alpha\alpha^{-1}$ that $\beta = \alpha^{-1}$, but you don't give a reason why.

In 2, you conclude from $\alpha\beta_1 = \alpha\beta_2$ that $\beta_1 = \beta_2$, and this time you do give a reason. However, as José Carlos Santos points out, you give no justification for concluding that if $\alpha(\beta_1 - \beta_2) = 0$ then $\beta_1 - \beta_2 = 0$. The only obvious way to justify this is by multiplying both sides by an inverse of $\alpha$. In 2 (unlike 1), you can do this without logical circularity. Still, the proof is unnecessarily complicated.

---

Let $\alpha = x + iy$. We are given that $\alpha \ne 0$, i.e. that $x \ne 0$ or $y \ne 0$.

Let $\beta = u + iv$: then $\alpha\beta = (xu - yv) + i(xv + yu)$.

The equation $\alpha\beta = 1$ is therefore equivalent to two simultaneous linear equations in real variables $u$ and $v$:
\begin{align*}
xu - yv & = 1, \\
xv + yu & = 0.
\end{align*}
It is up to you now to solve these equations for $u$ and $v$, with the help of the condition that $x \ne 0$ or $y \ne 0$.

The fact that a solution exists means that an inverse $\beta$ of $\alpha$ exists.

The fact that the solution is unique means that the inverse $\beta$ is unique - and *now* one can denote it by $\alpha^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain everything. This is a very nice way of doing the proof, since it proves existence and uniqueness at the same time. And your post also does well in clarifying Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\alpha = a_R+a_Ii$ in $\mathbb C$ with $a_R, a_I \in \mathbb R$ and $a_R$ or $a_I$ non-zero, let $\beta = b_R+b_Ii, $ where $$b_R=\frac {a_R}{a_R^2+a_I^2}$$ and

$$b_I=\frac {-a_I}{a_R^2+a_I^2}.$$

Since $a_R$ or $a_I$ is non-zero, $a_R^2+a_I^2$ is non-zero, so $b_R$ and $b_I$ exist as real numbers and $\beta \in \mathbb C$.

You can show that $\alpha \beta = 1$.

Comment: As per the comments to OP's question, we multiply numerator and denominator of $1 \over {a_R+a_Ii}$ by the complex conjugate of the denominator in order to get an expression of the form $b_R+b_Ii$

Answer (score 1):

With $$\alpha=x+iy,\beta=a+bi$$ we get
$$ax-by+i(ay+bx)=1$$ so you have to solve
$$ax-by=1$$ and $$ay+bx=0$$
solving this system you will get
$$(a^2+b^2)x=a$$ if $$a\neq 0$$ so $$x=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: How did you conclude that $ax-by+i(ay+bx)=1$?

Comment: The problem states $$\alpha\beta=1$$ for $$\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$$

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying now. I will edit with a new proof.

Comment: Why can we do this not? We have to prove the $$\beta$$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: I think we will get this by the ansatz above.

Comment: I think we actually get something like $(a^2+b^2)x = -b$. But how does this all help in the proof?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner:  I think you meant $(a^2+b^2)x=\pmb a$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof *assumes* that each complex number has an inverse. You are supposed to *prove* that. And how do you know that $\alpha(\beta_1-\beta_2)=0$ and $\alpha\neq0$ implies that $\beta_1-\beta_2=0$?

Comment: Since $\dfrac{0}{\alpha} = 0 \ \forall \ \alpha \not= 0$, no?

Comment: And I will edit the first part with a new proof now.

Comment: Concerning your question, I would say that$$0=\alpha^{-1}\times0=\alpha^{-1}\alpha(\beta_1-\beta_2)=\left(\alpha\alpha^{-1}\right)(\beta_1-\beta_)\beta_1-\beta_2.$$

Comment: Ok, thanks. So this would fix the second part by making it more rigorous?

Comment: Yes, it would fix it.