# (Continuation): Proof that for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha\neq0$, there exists a unique $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha\beta=1$ .

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

A question about this same proof was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128789/proof-for-every-alpha-in-mathbbc-with-alpha-not-0-there-exists-a-u), but the thread of answers left out one of the of the details involved with finalizing the proof that I'm a little hesitant on continuing along with on my own, which is why I still wanted to write my own question.

To state what I'm trying to prove: one the exercises from Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right (3rd Ed)* is to prove--using only the definitions of complex addition and complex multiplication--that

> for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha\neq0$, there exists a unique $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha\beta = 1$.

I won't bother with showing *exactly* how I went about writing this proof, since my approach happened to be almost exactly the same as Calum Gilhooley in the aforementioned question. I'll instead start with the part where he left off, and show where my issue is:

The goal is to solve for $u, v$ in terms of $x, y$, so we can write $\beta$ in terms of the real and imaginary parts of $\alpha$. Doing so, using the system of equations provided, yields
$$
\begin{align*}
u &= \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \\
v &= -\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}
\end{align*}
$$

From here, if we plug this expression into $\beta = u + vi$, we get the following:
$$\beta = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} - i\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} $$

Now, ideally, my next step would be to use a difference of squares argument to put $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$:
$$
\beta = \frac{x - iy}{x^2 + y^2}\\
= \frac{x - iy}{(x + iy)(x - iy)} \\
\therefore \beta = \frac{1}{x + iy} = \frac{1}{\alpha}
$$

But I'm not entirely sure about the second step, where the $x - iy$ term gets cancelled out--doesn't that make the assumption that some complex number has an inverse such that when the two are multiplied by each other, their product is 1?

I don't really know how else to continue this proof, so I'm kind of stuck here. Any help at all would be appreciated, and please let me know if I need to include more details to make this question more clear.

Comment: You have $\alpha = x+iy$, and you found  $\beta = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} - i\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}$ as candidate for the multiplicative inverse. All you have to do now is to verify that $\alpha \cdot \beta = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Martin R  wrote in the comments, you can verify that the $\beta$ you found solves $\alpha \beta =1.$  The other piece is to show that $\beta$ is unique.

Assume $\gamma$ with $\alpha \gamma=1$.  You can show, with a little algebra, that $\gamma - \beta$ must equal zero, so that $\beta$ is unique.